# How to draw an inclined line and parallelly put the text on it in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Now, I'm making some hypothesis graph and I made this graph.

```
x<- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
y<- c(100,90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20,10,1)
a<- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
b<- c(1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100)
dataA<- data.frame (x,y)
dataB<- data.frame (a,b)

  geom_line(data=dataA, aes(x=x, y=y), col="Dark red", size=1) +
  geom_line(data=dataB, aes(x=a, y=b), col="Dark blue", size=1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,12,1), limits = c(0,12)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,120,10), limits = c(0,120)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=70, linetype="dashed", color = "Black", size=1) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=50, linetype="dashed", color = "Black", size=1) +
  
  #geom_text(aes(fontface=6), x=11, y=110, label=paste("% distal\n","grains"), size=6, col="Dark blue") +
  geom_text(aes(fontface=6), x=10, y=75, label="AGW (90th percentile)", size=5, col="Black") +
  geom_text(aes(fontface=6), x=10, y=55, label="AGW (10th percentile)", size=5, col="Black") +
  
  xlab(bquote('x ('~m^2*')')) +
  ylab(bquote('y (mg '~grain^-1*')')) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text (face = "plain", size = 18, color = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),  #element_blank()) element_text(size= 14)
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(size = 0.5, colour = "black"))+
  windows(width=5.5, height=5)
```

[image]

As an alternatives, I need to present such as below graph, but I don't know how to draw an inclined line, starting a specific point of y-axis. Also, I would like to add a text on the line in a parallel position. Could you tell me how I can do this?

Many thanks!!

[image]

Comment: You could use `geom_abline` and `annotate` with an `angle`, see https://community.rstudio.com/t/annotation-aligned-with-abline/26411/2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a concrete example based on @Waldi 's comment:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Change line to what you want
line <- data.frame(x = c(10,30), y = c(300,50))
line = lm(formula = line$y ~ line$x)$coefficients

# ratio required for unequal axis scales
ratio <- 1/15

# get angle of the line
angle <- atan(line[2] * ratio) * 180 / pi

# plot it
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_abline(slope = line[2], intercept = line[1], color = "blue") +
    coord_equal(ratio = ratio) +
    annotate(
        geom = "text", 
        x = 20, 
        y = 20 * line[2] + line[1], 
        label = "My Line", 
        color = "blue", 
        angle = angle, 
        vjust = -1 # offset so text isn't directly on the line
    )
```

[image]